# Having issue in Downloading Google Documents using .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, google-drive-api, google-docs-api

I have created sample web application for access google drive APIs.

1. Enabled google drive documents APIsusing my google account.
2. Downloaded credential.json file and included inside the project.
3. Uploaded one document to my google drive with these below code

```
UserCredential credential;
string[] scopes = new string[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive,
                    DriveService.Scope.DriveAppdata,
                    DriveService.Scope.DriveFile,
                    DriveService.Scope.DriveMetadataReadonly,
                    DriveService.Scope.DriveReadonly,
                    DriveService.Scope.DriveScripts
};

using (var stream = new FileStream(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
{
  string credPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "token.json";
  credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
scopes,
"user",
CancellationToken.None, 
new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
 }

DriveService driveService = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
 HttpClientInitializer = credential,
ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
 });

FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload request;
using (var stream = new System.IO.FileStream(fileName,                                            System.IO.FileMode.Open))
{
   request = driveService.Files.Create(fileMetadata, stream, mimeType);
   request.Fields = "id";
   request.Upload();
}

file = request.ResponseBody;
```

4. Download file stream

```
 var request = service.Files.Get(fileId);
                    var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

                    request.MediaDownloader.ProgressChanged +=
                        (IDownloadProgress progress) =>
                        {
                            switch (progress.Status)
                            {
                                case DownloadStatus.Downloading:
                                    {                                       
                                        break;
                                    }
                                case DownloadStatus.Completed:
                                    {
                                        var bytearray = stream.ToArray(); 
                                     System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(SavedLocation, bytearray );
                                        break;
                                    }
                                case DownloadStatus.Failed:
                                    {                                       
                                        break;
                                    }
                            }
                        };
                    request.Download(stream);
```

But file stream is not properly download in random cases.

Refer Link: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads#downloading_google_documents

How can achieve this?

Comment: `But file stream is not properly download in random cases.` what does that mean? Have you checked the contents of the stream *after* the process completes?

Comment: Yes i saved the stream as file. That file not reflected my changes
 `System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(SavedLocation, stream.ToArray());`

Comment: Can you give us an example of the issue.

Comment: I have edited file with some values. I returned that file id to get stream after auto saving. I saved downloaded stream value as file. But my edited changes not reflected in that file completely.

Comment: and your sure your not saving it to a different file id? are you loading the latest revision?

Comment: Yes, i am not saving with different id. Google auto saved all my changes immediately. Then i pass file id to download stream

Comment: Have you tried to wait a few minutes after the save? It could be a propagation issue.

Comment: yes, i waited. But in random cases its also not working.